# Simulate a graph from a certain distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, sampling

I am wondering if anyone can indicate whether the following is a solved problem. I don't care about time of the algorithm currently.

Consider a general probability distribution F on simple graphs with number of vertices n. The distribution is exchangeable on vertices.

In general, how can we sample from such a distribution on simple graphs with number of vertices N, such that if we pick any n vertices out of N, the corresponding probability distribution on the subgraph is F? Asymptotic distribution is also acceptable.

I am also curious about existence and uniqueness of the distribution.

Comment: If $F$ gives 0 probability to empty sets and complete graphs, Ramsey's theorem says there are no such graphs for very large $N$. More general versions of Ramsey's theorem eliminate more cases. The existence question is indeed interesting. I feel that the theory of pseudorandom graphs may be relevant.

Comment: Thank you! I am sure that the distribution I am looking at gives positive probability to any possible simple graphs...Would you give me some sources that I can look at?

Comment: A nice survey of pseudorandom graphs is at https://people.math.ethz.ch/~sudakovb/pseudo-random-survey.pdf .  It isn't my field so I'm not sure how much it will help.

Comment: For my purpose F doesn't need to be Erdos-Renyi at all. What I am actually looking at is here...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_random_graph_models Anyway, I realized how this problem could be...Thanks. You have been very helpful.